# Graphing the expected magnitude of an estimate $\hat{\theta}$, given statistical significance, as a function of the true $\theta$

Tags: estimation, data-visualization, bias, publication-bias

I'm looking to start with an assumed true parameter $\theta$, and taking the normal distribution of the estimate $\hat{\theta}$ with mean $\theta$ and a known standard deviation (suppose it's $0.10$), and compute $E ( |\hat{\theta}|$, given $|\hat{\theta}| > 0.20)$, i.e. the expected magnitude of the estimate when selected for statistical significance. The goal is, using R, to plot this $E ( |\hat{\theta}|$, given $|\hat{\theta}| > 0.20)$ as a function of the true $\theta$.

See page 3 and the top of page 4 of the following for an example: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/incrementalism_3.pdf

Comment: You don't seem to ask any questions here. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `R` function that calculates the bias (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15977987)):

```
bias <- function(m, sem) {

  func <- function(x, ...) {x * dnorm(x, ...)}

  ((abs(integrate(func, -Inf, -2*sem, mean=m, sd = sem)$value) + integrate(func, 2*sem, Inf, mean=m, sd = sem)$value)/
      ((pnorm(-2*sem, mean=m, sd=sem) - pnorm(-Inf, mean=m, sd=sem)) + (pnorm(Inf, mean=m, sd=sem) - pnorm(2*sem, mean=m, sd=sem)))) - m

}
```

Let's test it with the examples from Gelman:

```
sapply(c(0, 0.1, 0.25), bias, sem = 0.12)
[1] 0.28478586 0.19877756 0.08946908
```

Seems correct. Now let's reproduce their Figure 1:

```
theta <- seq(0, 0.6, length.out = 100)

b <- sapply(theta, bias, sem = 0.12)

plot(b~theta, type = "l", las = 1, ylab = "Bias", lwd = 2)
abline(h = 0)
```

[image: Gelman Figure 1]

Now with your values:

```
theta <- seq(0, 0.6, length.out = 100)

b2 <- sapply(theta, bias, sem = 0.1)

plot(b2~theta, type = "l", las = 1, col = "red", ylab = "Bias", lwd = 2, ylim = c(0, 0.3))
lines(b~theta, col  = "black", lwd = 2)
legend("topright", legend = c("Gelman", "tres14"), lwd = c(2, 2), col = c("red", "black"), bty = "n")
abline(h = 0)
```

[image: Bias for both values]